# How to avoid ambiguity of the antecedent of a relative clause?

Tags: relative-clauses, ambiguity

I wrote this technical text, which I found ambiguous:

> What's a child expression? It's a call expression inside a function,
>   which represents a parent call expression.

For the purposes of discussion in this question, let's simplify it to this:

> What's a child sphere? **It's a sphere inside a cube, which represents a
>   parent shape.**

How do I rewrite this sentence in a non-ambiguous way, to link the verb *represents* to the noun *cube*?

(Also, hypothetically, how would I rewrite it if I wanted to link the verb to *sphere*?)

Comment: A complete sentence and surrounding sentences would surely be helpful to us.  There are numerous ways to accomplish this.  One way, which may not be appropriate depending on the context, would be to use two sentences: "It's a sphere inside a cube.  The cube represents..."

Comment: As written, with a comma after **cube**, the sentence means that it's the positioning of the sphere inside the cube that represents whatever.....

Comment: @RonaldSole Sorry, I don't feel I got your point. Do you mean that `cube` is already linked here to the verb because of the comma? So without a comma `sphere` would be linked to the verb?

Comment: Thanks.  In that case, Tashus's idea will work, but there are other ways of getting the same point across.

Comment: @JasonBassford I never even thought about this way to interpret my sentence. But now I see. Interesting! Thanks! English is so ambiguous to me.

Comment: @NurbolAlpysbayev Ha! You replied to a comment I made (and then deleted) before completely reading the question. For others, my comment had been that *my* natural inclination would be to think of *which* as representing the combined single object *a sphere inside a cube*. (Like a piece single piece of artwork.) In other words, I didn't think of it as ambiguous at all until I read the read the rest of the question. But the question is actually how to refer to the sphere component specifically.

Comment: There is no ambiguity if you use a that clause. Antecedents in **that** clauses apply to the antecedent noun. Not to an entire phrase. It would only refer to the cube.

Comment: @Lambie You have asserted this rule, but do you have any evidence of it? Assuming the rule does indeed exist, it is certainly idiomatic to allow such clauses to be distant from their antecedents in violation of such a rule. If someone said, "I hear a voice in my head that isn't really there," would you assume that they were missing their head?

Comment: It is not a grammar rule. It is a style rule. "I hear a voice in my head, which isn't really there." I assume you are writing, not chatting on Facebook.  Next? But clearly, my structure leaves no room for ambiguity. You were looking to not be ambiguous, right? Not to disambiguate every single possible sentence....goodness me. Style and grammar are not the same thing. So, if you are writing, you might want to pay heed to style. And I have given you the key to writing it in an non-ambiguous way!

Comment: @Lambie Style rules are closer to "best practices". Changing from "that" to "which" doesn't change the ambiguity; it only makes the clause nonessential. The ambiguity is whether "that/which represents a parent shape" refers to "cube", to "a sphere inside a cube", or to "sphere". Your answer does nothing to resolve that ambiguity. Asserting, "a 'that' clause can only refer to the adjacent word," does not make it so. If this rule is so prolific, simply provide evidence for it.

Comment: @Lambie: *I heard the song of a nightingale, which was music to my ears* (***which*** refers to ***the song***). *I heard the song of a nightingale, which had recently taken up residence in my garden* (***which*** refers to ***a nightingale***). Only ***pragmatics***, not grammar, allows us to unambiguously determine the referent of ***which*** in such constructions.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can make the sentence less ambiguous by expressing the intended concept more explicitly. For example:

> It's a sphere inside a cube, with the cube representing the parent shape of the sphere.

or

> It's a sphere inside a cube, where the cube represents the parent shape of the sphere.

Comment: Thank you! I feel now it looks much better, however can you please explain the word `with` here? So this word has a meaning other than uniting things? Is it used here in the same or similar meaning as `where`? Can `where` be used here as well?

Comment: +1.   **where** can also be used if you change the participle **representing** to a tensed verb (*...inside a cube, where the cube represents...*), and you can even say *...inside a cube, the cube representing ...*

Comment: Yes. Sometimes you can resolve an ambiguity by changing the word order or being more careful in selection of pronouns, etc. But often, the simplest and clearest thing to do is to add a few words to explicitly say what you mean.

Comment: There is no ambiguity in: a sphere inside a cube that represents the parent shape. That is a restricted clause with the that clause modifying cube.

Comment: @Lambie Again, the ambiguity is "a sphere inside **a cube that represents the parent shape**" vs. "**a sphere inside a cube** that represents the parent shape" or "a sphere inside **a cube, which represents the parent shape**" vs. "**a sphere inside a cube**, which represents the parent shape." The clause can apply to the entire noun phrase just as easily as to the single adjacent noun. Whether the clause is restrictive does not change the ambiguity.

Answer (score 4):

Do you need to convert the single sentence to a single sentence? If so, I would go with the approaches chosen by Tashus ("... where the cube represents" or "... with the cube representing...") or Utkarsh Singh (using "former" or "latter" to refer to the item in question). If you're not restricted to a single sentence, you can simply repeat the noun in a new sentence:

```
It's a sphere inside a cube. The cube represents a parent shape...
```

UPDATE: As David Richerby points out, you could then combine the sentences with a semicolon or a connecting word:

```
It's a sphere inside a cube; the cube represents a parent shape...
It's a sphere inside a cube, and the cube represents a parent shape...
It's a sphere inside a cube, where the cube represents a parent shape...
```

Comment: Or join the two sentences back into one with a semicolon or "and".

Comment: @DavidRicherby, yes.

Comment: Or use a restricted clause with that. It's a bird in the tree that turns pink every night.

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, the usage of the determiner "which" herein will inevitably lead to ambiguity. One of the ways to avoid this, while still retaining the word "represents", can be to instead use a co-ordinating conjunction like "and" - It's a sphere inside a cube, ***and*** the former represents...(in case the subject is sphere).

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to disambiguate in *speech* (which is after all the only *real* language, to a first approximation) is simply to stress the word ***sphere*** and introduce a slightly longer pause before the next word. Orthographically, that would be represented as...

> *It's a **sphere** - inside a cube representing the "parent" shape*

(Note that I've included "parent" in scare quotes because I don't exactly understand the usage in context. If OP knows his target audience *will* understand the expression, there's no need to call attention to the potentially problematic usage.)

Comment: Hi, thank you! Is it really orthographically correct? I mean how you wrote it, with the hyphen? I mean, I doubt I ever saw such constructions, but maybe I just didn't notice them.

Comment: Per my first sentence - real language is almost entirely a ***spoken*** phenomenon. How to actually ***write*** it is just a matter of convention, with different (but potentially all perfectly competent) writers choosing different orthographies. Many people would be quite happy to use a comma instead of a hyphen. I really can't see that anyone would claim it would be "ungrammatical" to use a comma (or full stop), but people might well disagree over the validity of other punctuation marks here, such as a colon, semicolon, or ellipsis (three dots). We'd all ***say*** it the same though.

Comment: Interesting. I can't stop be surprised by english language and overall philosophy. In russian, which I learnt in school orthography is almost as precise science as math is. Thank you so much!

Comment: @NurbolAlpysbayev: You had the benefit of many historical [*Reforms of Russian orthography*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reforms_of_Russian_orthography). To a lesser extent, Americans had the benefit of at least *some* reforms to spelling with Webster, but the English language has never really been under "State control", so it's not obvious how major changes could be enforced anyway. Particularly in Britain, where many if not most people could read and write a *very* long time ago, and wouldn't like to live through an age of "double standards".

Comment: The real problem with trying to standardize English spelling is, whose pronunciations do you use? I'm reminded of a *House Hunters International* episode where the New Zealander real estate lady kept talking about the "dick"... which turned out to be the deck.

Comment: @Martha I used to be irritated by such a lack of standardisation and variety of accents etc. However these irritations force a curious person (like me) to research roots of this and in the end to be more historically-educated, which is good. Just my thought in addition to yours.

Comment: @FumbleFingers to be pedantic about it, it should not be a hyphen (which is narrow, and used in constructs like "fumble-fingered" (heh) and at the end of a line when a word is broken due to the column width allowed) but a _dash_ (which is wider).  The old rule for typewriters was to use two hyphens to represent a dash, but with computers we can actually use the "figure dash" "‒" "en dash" "–" and "em dash" "—" (named for the widths of the "n" and "m" characters, the latter being the wider version).  If you have a Windows computer, use Character Map's Advanced view and search for "dash".

Comment: @MontyHarder That's what exists in russian language (hyphen vs dash). Good to know english follows this rule as well.

Comment: Where is the ambiguity? Can you please answer that? The lemmings are going over the cliff.

Comment: @Lambie There are several comments explaining the ambiguity. The ambiguity is whether the clause refers to "cube", to "a sphere inside a cube", or to "sphere".

Comment: @MontyHarder: You're quite right, of course. Truth is I often forget which is which out of ***dash*** and ***hyphen***. I'm a bit inclined to use them interchangeably anyway though, because whenever the distinction really matters I use ***em-dash*** and ***en-dash***. Whatever - if we're gonna get picky about it, maybe I should have included ***dot-dot-dot*** (3 *actual* consecutive full stops) as yet another alternative orthographic convention for the context (as opposed to the dedicated Unicode character for ellipsis, namely U+2026 or “**…**” :)

Comment: There is no ambiguity here at all. The problem is that the English speakers seem to be forgetting their grammar. And none of them (above) has really addressed the issue in this specific sentence. Fumble Fingers does not specifically address the issue here. He is speaking in generalities.

Comment: @Lambie You are mistaken. I have clearly explained the ambiguity to you several times. Your comments rejecting the premise of a valid question are not helpful.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of the particular sentence you gave,

> What's a child sphere? It's a sphere inside a cube, which represents a parent shape.

There's only one thing wrong with it: the comma.  You want

> What's a child sphere? It's a sphere inside a cube which represents a parent shape.

When parsing a sentence, the comma gives us an indication as to the sentence structure.  In your sentence, the comma indicates that the clause "inside a cube" is complete and you're beginning a relative clause referring to the sphere.  Commas also correspond to pauses in normal speech, so that may help (though the correspondence isn't perfect).

This doesn't mean that this is the right sentence to use; while it's (technically) unambiguous, someone who is not reading carefully is likely to read it wrong.

Answer (score -2):

> It's a sphere inside a **cube that represents** a parent shape. The
>   **that** clause only goes with the cube.

There's a market along the **road that runs to town**.

There is no ambiguity here at all.

> It's a man in a *balloon that floats** on the water.

My advice is kill the which in this case.

**"that represents a parent shape" is a restrictive clause modifying cube. It does not modify: sphere inside a cube, which is a noun plus a prepositional phrase.**

> - **restrictive clauses modify a noun.** Not a noun and a preposition phrase as found in the OP's sentence.

Example of an **unrestricted clause** from the Oxford Dictionary [online] made into a restricted one.

> [clauses, restricted and unrestricted](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/grammar/relative-clauses)
>
> It says: **A restrictive relative clause provides essential information about the noun to which it refers.**

- unrestricted: The items, **which are believed to be family heirlooms**, included a grandfather clock worth around £3,000.
- restricted: The items **that are believed to be family heirlooms**, included a grandfather clock worth around £3,000.

The lines in the painting **that hangs on the North Wall** are not straight.

The other sentence in the question using a restrictive clause:

> It's a call expression inside a function that represents a parent call
>   expression.

Comment: Not my DV, but I'm not sure that this is correct. "There's a market along the road that sells firewood." is a perfectly reasonable sentence where **that sells firewood** obviously refers to **market**.

Comment: The way I have written your sentence from your question is devoid of ambiguity and it uses clear, simple grammar. Are you trying to make your sentence clear or discuss all possible ambiguities in English?

Comment: I agree that my sentence is ambiguous, as someone could interpret it to mean that the road sells firewood. However, a sentence can still be grammatically acceptable despite ambiguity. I can find no grammatical rule that such clauses must be adjacent to their antecedents, and I can find plenty of examples to the contrary.

Comment: @Lambie & Tashus I'll just leave this one here:

"Hiking along a trail in the woods, a dead deer was discovered by a troop of Boy Scouts."

(I don't know how a dead deer hikes through the woods.)

Comment: @tashus Yes. Sometimes we determine how to link parts of a sentence based on grammar, and sometimes we do it based on our knowledge of the world. I'm reminded of a headline I saw once, "Bear attacks farmer with ax". I presume the writer meant that the farmer had an ax, and not the bear. Either is grammatically possible, but as in the real world bears rarely use axes to attack people, most of us instinctively ignore that interpretation. Of course there are many jokes based on saying something that is technically ambiguous but with such an obvious interpretation, and then saying the opposite.

Comment: Folks, there is no ambiguity in my sentence at all. What is the matter with everyone? And the OP was imagining an ambiguity that simply is not there....

Comment: @Lambie You say there is no ambiguity because "that represents a parent shape" can only apply to "cube", since they are adjacent. However, I don't believe that rule is as steadfast as you think. It could instead apply to the noun phrase "a sphere inside a cube" as a whole. It could even apply to "sphere" alone, although I agree that stylistically this would be a poor choice due to the lack of clarity resulting from the distance between the phrase and its intended antecedent. However, poor stylistic choices that introduce ambiguity are not equivalent to incorrect grammar.

Comment: I have edited my answer and explained a restrictive clause. restrictive clauses modify nouns. There's your rule. For your information, "a sphere inside a cube" ***is not a noun phrase***. **It is a noun followed by a prepositional phrase**.

Comment: @Lambie Restrictive vs unrestrictive only distinguishes between essential clauses (i.e. ones that change the definition of the antecedent) and nonessential clauses (i.e. ones that do not change the definition); the distinction is tangential to the OP's question. None of the rules state that the antecedent must be immediately followed by the clause. Also, perhaps your understanding of a noun phrase differs from the standard definition. Prepositional phrases are explicitly listed as one of the possible components of a noun phrase. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_phrase#Components

Comment: Yhey don't state it because it's obvious, And:  "a sphere inside a cube" is not a ***noun phrase***. Ask anyone native speaker with a decent level of grammatical understanding. ***a sphere inside a cube = a noun plus a prepositional phrase***. That is basic English grammar.

Comment: @Lambie Are you a native English speaker? Do you have a formal education in English grammar? You seem to be confused on this issue and resistant to any information that contradicts your preconceptions. The ambiguity is certainly present; several native speakers have confirmed this. **A noun and a prepositional phrase can quite readily form a noun phrase. Such constructions are** ***explicitly listed*** **in the Wikipedia article on noun phrases**.